# Metrics on the space of $C^{*}$ algebras

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I think that there is  a metric on the huge space of all $C^{*}$ algebras. What is the explicit

definition of this metric?may you introduce me  a reference?

Moreover  is the restriction of this metric to commutative $C^{*}$ algebras gives us  a discrete metric? by discrete I mean "every commutative $C^{*}$ algebra has a neighborhood, with respect to this metric,  which contains no other commutative $C^{*}$ algebra"

Comment: What makes you think that such a metric exists?

Comment: I heard this from a participant, when I was participating  in  a workshop on NCG.(about 9 years ago)

Comment: I also heard this from an speaker who gave  a talk on NCG about 6 years ago. I remember he said that this metric is defined by A. Connes. In that time I did not peruse the details. But now I am interested to know about this metric

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably the most standard metric is [Banach-Mazur distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach-Mazur_compactum), and there is indeed [a theorem due to Amir](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03008398#page-1) which says that if the Banach-Mazur distance between $C(K)$ and $C(L)$ is less than $2$ then $K$ and $L$ are homeomorphic. There's also something called the [Kadets distance](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9709211v1.pdf) which is basically a linearized Gromov-Hausdorff distance. I don't know what the Kadets distance says about commutative C*-algebras.

---

Adding an edit to call attention to Caleb Eckhardt's comment. Caleb point out that CB Banach-Mazur distance is a better candidate (I agree) and cites [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1970) which shows that if two C*-algebras have sufficiently small CB Banach-Mazur distance, and one of them is nuclear (in particular, commutative) then they are isomorphic.

Comment: The completely bounded Banach-Mazur distance (which is just Banach-Mazur for commutative C*-algebras) would probably be more useful for noncommutative C*-algebras.  Ricard and Roydor recently showed a (completely bounded) analogue of the Amir-Cambern theorem for nuclear C*-algebras http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1970

Comment: NiK,Caleb thank you very much for your valuable answer and comment

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is the Kadison-Kastler metric on C*-subalgebras of $B(H)$, which is just the Hausdorff distance between their unit balls. [This paper](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~roger.smith/papers/lengthfinal.pdf) gives references to a number of  results about stability under perturbation, which include the case where one of the algebras is separable and abelian; [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.4953) generalizes to the case where one of the algebras is separable and nuclear.